Standard Community Responses to Poor Questions and Answers
With this feature, I have begun trying to write some standard responses to certain types of questions. I tend to write these as I see the need for a new one (when responding to a specific question, I'll try to write a "form" answer).
I thought others may also appreciate sharing and/or participating in creating some of these standard responses, and I'd love to see how others go about answering. I was thinking we could do one answer per response type ("add initial research", "opinion based question", etc), and see where it goes from there!

I tend to use something like the following, especially with newcomers' questions, when a question is unclear possibly due to lack of information on what they are researching

Hi [@Username] and welcome to CogSciSE. What research have you done to come up with ..... ? What references can you provide to give a background to what you are asking about?


Relating to Pseudoscience

Welcome to Cognitive Sciences! This question appears to be off-topic as questions relating to pseudoscience are off-topic on Cognitive Sciences.

With lack of a better definition, I think that the link to the "list of pseudosciences" on Wikipedia is important (to let users know what will or won't be classified as pseudoscience).
I know we (as a community) haven't formally decided one way or the other on the appropriateness of pseudoscience questions, but I propose using this reason (or a reason that lists what you classify as pseudoscience) when choosing to vote to closed a question as pseudoscience (if you choose to do so).

No Initial Research
This one will probably also be edgy as we are about to get the new close reason, but I still think a form comment may be useful. 

Hello and welcome to Cognitive Sciences! Will you please provide the results of your initial research? Thank you!

Hopefully is welcoming while stating the expectation that initial research is done, and asking for it. This may be nicely supplemented by a link to the new close reason's help documentation which, in my mind, will detail our expectation on ``initial research''.

Personal advice sought
Similar to the standard comment given by MedicalSciences.SE I comment with

Welcome to Psychology.SE! I am sorry, but for a number of reasons outlined in this meta post we can not, and will not, give advice or potential diagnoses for any specific individual. If you or anyone else has a question regarding personal mental health, advice from a doctor should be sought. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the tour, visit the How to Ask page and Psychology & Neuroscience Meta.

there are shortcodes you can use to help so the markdown used when posting the comment is:
Welcome to Psychology.SE! I am sorry, but [for a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic) we can not, and will not, give advice or potential diagnoses for any specific individual. If you or anyone else has a question regarding personal mental health, advice from a doctor should be sought. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta].

Subjective

I'm voting this question closed as seems likely to generate opinion-based answers. Please see our help center for more details about opinion based questions and what questions are appropriate here at Cognitive Sciences, and feel free to edit as needed.


Personally, I dislike it when someone says we frown upon when I actually like the question. Further, [too] many questions here are quite subjective. I think you need to keep in mind that pob close-votes are generally used the other way around, namely for questions that are likely to generate opinion-based answers. Lastly, pob close-votes already generate an automated answer which is actually pretty good.

@AliceD Really? Perhaps it is because I post an additional comment, but I haven't seen the auto-generated answer... To test, I just voted to close my question here for this reason...

@AliceD Updated: hopefully better (though if we have auto-ones for this, there is no need). Perhaps I could ask: are we supposed to have auto-generated responses for all closings?

When the comment ends up being the same as 'on hold' reasons, I see no point in leaving a comment. This is what the specific close reasons are for in the first please. A comment should either elaborate, or make it more specific to the site.

@StevenJeuris Hmm I wouldn't disagree if the close reasons automatically generated a comment, but in the couple of days that it can take a question to be closed a user (specifically a new user) may appreciate the feedback and the point in the right direction.

@mfloren I see. So you advocate posting the comment prior to the questions being put on hold (while close reasons are still coming in)?

@StevenJeuris Yes sir! I think that even a form answer can give newer users a push in the right direction on improving their posts (and let them know that someone is trying to help them). For me, the ideal would be that the question is edited immediately (and never gets closed at all).
